# Java Access To "Video Controller" In Windows

Tags: java, windows, image, video, capture

Is there a way to access a device classed as a video controller from Java? I can capture from a webcam via an applet I created, but need to capture an image from a security camera that is being fed into what Windows Device Manager classes as a "Video Controller".

I had thought the same code I used for the webcam would work, much to my disappointment.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Beside going to the JNI route, I would definitely take a look to OpenCV, that would do it for you effortless.

OpenCV provide a DLL that you can easily invoke from Java.
You can then use it to capture and **manipulate** images coming from a webcam, in real-time.

But the really interesting part of OpenCV reside in the fact that it is a Computer Vision API. 
As such, you can for e.g. easily perform motion detection, face recognition, etc, what sounds to me to be a must in the video security software world.

To capture an image from a camera, see the [VideoCapture](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html) method.
Example of usage [here](https://gist.github.com/b95505017/6862032).

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking into this.  It looks promising and I'll be tinkering with it this weekend.  Will, obviously, keep everyone posted.